# If all our sites are secure (HTTPS), is setting the "secure" flag on cookies redundant?

Tags: security, cookies, setcookie

If all our sites are secure (HTTPS), is setting the `secure` flag on cookies redundant?

Are there any pros or cons of setting / not setting the `secure` if we only have secure sites in our setup?

Comment: A more important security flag for cookies is [httponly](https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/)

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not redundant.

Consider the following scenarios.

Situation normal:

```
User --> Your Website (example.com)
```

Man-In-The-Middle situation:

```
User --> MITM --> Your Website (example.com)
```

If your website listens on port 80 for plain HTTP, and port 443 for HTTPS, then the MITM would have to pass the HTTPS traffic from the User to Your Website as pure TCP data, otherwise the User would get a certificate warning due to the fact the attacker does not have the private key for the `example.com` SSL/TLS cerfificate.

However, they can still intercept plain HTTP traffic on port 80. Therefore if `example.com` sets the cookie

```
AuthenticationSession=0d8d7050f48dc858975c48d32796cd2e5bad2d18
```

without the Secure flag, the attacker can still intercept this on port 80.

If your website **does not listen** on port 80 the situation is as follows.

```
User -tcp80--> MITM
User -tcp443-> MITM -tcp443-> Your Website (example.com)
```

So, although there is nothing listening at your end on port 80, the attacker could inject the following

```
<img src="http://example.com/foo.jpg" />
```

into another request the User makes:

```
User -tcp80--> MITM --> example.org
```

Which causes the following to happen:

```
User -tcp80--> MITM intercepting example.com
```

sending the cookie to the attacker for `example.com`

Note that `http://example.com:443` will also cause the cookie data to be sent before the server realises it has not gotten an HTTPS handshake, exposing the cookie in the clear:

```
User --plain HTTP over tcp443--> example.com
```

In this situation the attacker does not have to be a Man-In-The-Middle, they could just be passively observing the connection to `example.com`.

Once the attacker grabs the main authentication cookie for a site, they can effectively hijack the User's session and be logged in as them.

If you want to make the Secure flag redundant, implement an [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) policy. This informs the browser never to connect to Your Website over plain HTTP until the `max-age` has expired (say 180 days).

Therefore any attacker trying to inject a plain HTTP URL in an image tag will have this changed to HTTPS by the browser, and therefore will render unreadable by anything other than the server. This is [known as a 307 internal redirect](https://www.troyhunt.com/understanding-http-strict-transport/):

> This is [the browser] saying
>   “I’m not even going to issue that request, instead I’m going to change
>   it to HTTPS then try again”

However, as a defence-in-depth approach and to provide support for older browsers, I would still include the Secure flag.

Cons? You will be sending the number of bytes within the string "`; secure`" extra, but only when the cookie is set. And if you need to use the cookie over plain HTTP, you cannot.

Answer (score 3):

> If all our sites are secure (HTTPS), is setting the secure flag on cookies redundant?

No, it isn't.

The secure flag prevents the cookie from being sent over HTTP.

Even if your server doesn't listen on port 80 at all (and most HTTPS sites also have an HTTP site that redirects to the HTTPS side), clients which *try* to connect to port 80 can be subject to man-in-the-middle attacks.

*Pros*

It protects the cookie

*Cons*

It costs an insignificant number of bytes.

Comment: > Even if your server doesn't listen on port 80 at all (and most HTTPS sites also have an HTTP site that redirects to the HTTPS side), clients which try to connect to port 80 can be subject to man-in-the-middle attacks.

But that's a totally different attack. Someone spoofing as my site, on port 80. Setting secure cookies wont help against that, does it?

Comment: Or are you saying, if someone does a man in the middle attack, secure cookies are secure? Hm. Ok.ay

Comment: "But that's a totally different attack" — Different to what? Your question is a general one about the point of secure cookies. Not about how they relate to any specific attack.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the secure flag is for the *browser* to never send the cookie over plain http, regardless of whether the application developer intended to send it only over https. Consider an attack where for example in an html editor form, an attacker can insert images. If he adds an image with a http://server source, the cookie will be sent plaintext unless set as secure. Of course there may be countless other ways to try and inject a plain http request.

If the application server only listens on tcp/443, that's more difficult for an attacker (he could still try things like http://server:443 and see how fast the server drops the obviously invalid connection). It's still the best practice to set all cookies as secure.

So it's not only about man in the middle.